# Passing an html string to a jQuery/Zepto constructor does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, parsing, constructor, zepto

If I pass an html string to a jQuery or Zepto constructor I expected it to create a DOM object with all the elements passed in. However it is only returning an object with the first element.

Is this expected or am I doing something really obviously wrong in that string?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6TUSN/

`o.html()` outputs: `This is the main content of the <strong>home</strong> index action` without even the `p` tag.

(Same results for jquery or zepto)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to get this working is to create a wrapper object and append the string to that. Is this a bug?

```
var s = '<p>The html</p>';

var wrapper = $('<div>');
wrapper.append(s);

console.log(wrapper.html());
```